# Write function in linux kernel module is called repeatedly

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I am writing a character device driver in C for Linux and have run into a problem where my `module_write` function is being called repeatedly. What could be causing this?

Attached is a screenshot of the command used to write to the device file and the kernel log output [image]

As you can see, it looks as though the `module_write` function is being called repeatedly. It doesn't matter how I write to the file (I tried using vim, echo and tee)

Source: https://gist.github.com/SamTebbs33/8ed6a1d165fae1ca27fff5b495d04797

Comment: That's noit how it works here. Read [æsk] and provide a [mcve]. With >3k reps, one should know the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep saying that 0 bytes were successfully written, so the program keeps trying to write its three bytes.

You should instead be returning the number of bytes you processed successfully from the buffer.